# How to redirect a form's get variables with IIS7?

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

Is it possible (and if so how) to redirect the url from a forms get variables into something more url friendly using IIS 7's URL Rewrite module.  An example would be

```
/Catalog/Search/Title=Something&Order=Price
```

into

```
/Catalog/Search/Title/Something/Order/Price
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, but you should dig into this article for how as there are some good details in it:
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-url-rewrite-module/